# Access 2013 failure to run query whilst application minimised

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I run a report - using either a simple query, complex (query builder) or via DoCmd.OpenReport(.....) then the report populates fine.

However I wish to run the application with the forms etc as Pop-ups, and the application minimised, or hidden - otherwise users will just access the database that way - and miss the logic that is integrated etc.

So I am Minimising the application using apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED)

However in this case, when I run the same reports as before - there is no data, just a blank report - not even the header!

Any ideas?

Julie

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do... Are your users supposed to interface with your application, or does it just automatically run reports when the database is opened? If I have code that minimizes (using your example), then runs a report, the report itself is hidden. If you want to prevent users from doing other things, then lock down the database and remove the menus, etc.

Comment: The User will access the form (modal popup) selecting their options, eg, items sold in "x" time frame etc - lots of standard reports available. I need the report to pop up (which it does) containing the correct data as per the user's filter criteria (which it does) - however if I hide or minimise the Access appliction (not the popup forms etc) then none of the data is included when the report pops up. - basically the query appears to fail

Comment: If I remove the menus etc from the access application etc, then the users still get the Access application, rather than just the dedicated entry screen to their custom app - I should say that everything else works, the users can add sales, new customers etc and switch around all the forms needed to use the custom application with the exception of the reports which are always blank. However open the access application to normal or maximised and then the reports populate

Comment: Hi I have uploaded an example DB here http://www.filedropper.com/demoreportfail - Please use with caution, it is OK as I uploaded it, but can't say it won't get hacked in the future - if you open the database, it will go to an entry screen where you can click for a standard report - which will be blank. - Now click the "Show maximised" button, and the app will open up - re-try the report and it will fill as normal - to view the code etc press the shift key when opening the db

Comment: Sorry forgot to say - you will have to save the file to disc, then open and allow content - after which it will work as described

Comment: OK, in the category of 'I don't have a clue why, but...' I went into your form, modified the macro that is called on 'Open Report' click and changed the 'Windows Mode' to ICON and it now works just fine...

Comment: Thanks, yes that appears to sort it, setting windows mode to Icon (via the macro and/or the doCmd.OpenForm () command in VBA) works. Not sure why this should be the case - I had tried acDialog (which is popup and modal) and acNormal but neither worked - never thought Icon would work! - so thanks, sorted

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it works, or needs to be the case, but setting windows mode to Icon (via the macro and/or the doCmd.OpenForm () command in VBA) works.

Nor can I claim the credit - Thanks to Wayne G Dunn